# How to analyse simple internet downtime log?

Tags: time-series, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have a log of internet downtime (timestamp + downtime in seconds) and I'd like to analyse it to try and spot trends, especially if I can see that it normally happens around specific times of the day, but any other useful info would also be good.

There are certainly lots of tools out there for log analysis, but they all seem incredibly complex and with steep learning curves for such a relatively easy query.

I'm so sorry for such a basic question, but I've exhausted Google and I simply have no idea what I'm doing. For background, I'm a programmer of 20+ years, but I am hoping there must be a simpler solution than to write a fairly complex program to analyse this, not to mention I'd then be coding for a specific answer, not a general analysis to discover unknown trends.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would start with some plots, first checking each component separately. Try a histogram to check the hourly distribution of timestamps, and then another one to check the distribution of downtime length.

Comment: I concur that drawing plots is the right way to start as long as the kind of pattern your looking for is so loosely defined. Start with a histogram with the hours (0:: to 23:59) on the x-axis and the frequency of downtimes at a given hour on the y. They say that one should draw lot's of graphs "to get a feeling for the data". A scripting language an a good graphics library can do a lot in terms of finding patterns.

Comment: Thank you ... those are great ideas. What software should I be using to do this though? Like I said, I really am a complete beginner at this stuff.

Comment: That is really up to you, if you are a programmer of 20+ years you really won't have issues figuring out how to create couple of plots in your language of choice (if by language of choice you mean a general scripting language, a compiled language is probably not the best tool). Having said that, I think a lot of people here would recommend R.

Comment: Understood. Thank you. Was hoping there might be an existing open source app that would have some predefined actions/graphs, but if not then I shall take your suggestions above and build something.